# How do I pass in an un-evaluated variable to a shell script, and have the script evaluate it after sourcing another script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that is sourcing a second script and need to do the following:

- I want to pass in a variable name to the first script like this: sh firstScript.sh variable=$variableName
- The first script will then source the second script, which contains the value of variableName
- I'm then going to print the evaluated variable

I know that I can do something like \$variableName to pass in the variable name, but I can't figure out how to get the first script to then evaluate the variable using the exported variables from the second script.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You can `eval` a string to have it interpreted as a shell command.

Comment: This is tagged `ssh` -- what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @thatotherguy - your answer pointed me in the right direction.  Something I should have mentioned in the original post and didn't think of is the variable is going to be in the middle of a string, like so:

sh firstScript.sh --message="This is a message \${variableName}"

eval won't work in this case, but I can pull out all variables in the string and use eval to evaluate each variable + do a string replace.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want:

firstScript.sh

```
varname="$1"
if [[ -z $varname ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 varname"
    exit
fi
source ./secondScript.sh

declare -n ref="$varname"
echo "varname=$varname value=$ref"
```

secondScript.sh

```
foo=2
```

Then execute the script with:

```
./firstScript.sh foo
```

Output:

```
varname=foo value=2
```

The `-n` option to the `declare` creates a reference to another variable.
The bash version should be 4.3 or later to enjoy the functionality.

**[Alternative]**

You can also write the `firstScript.sh` as:

firstScript.sh

```
varname="$1"
if [[ -z $varname ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 varname"
    exit
fi
source ./secondScript.sh

echo "varname=$varname value=${!varname}"
```

which will produce the same result.

The `${!varname}` notation is called `indirect expansion` in which `varname` is expanded as a name of a variable.
It has been introduced since bash2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks really close to what I need, but I'm on bash v4.1.2 & don't have the -n option.  Really good suggestion though.

Comment: @ChrisHandley thank you for your response. I've updated my answer with an alternative which will work with your bash. I should have included it in my previous answer. Would you please test it? BR,

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wound up doing:

I'm passing in an entire string, with the variable embedded in the middle of the string like so:

sh firstScript.sh --message="This is a message \${variableName}"

In the first script, I'm doing these steps:

1. Extract the entire string in to an array
2. Pull out the embedded variables
3. Evaluate the embedded variables against the sourced script
4. Do a string replace to put the value in the original string

When I was done, it looked like this:

```
IFS=';' args=(${@//--/;}); unset IFS

source secondScript.sh

case ${arg^^} in
  MESSAGE=*)
    message="${arg#*=}"
    messageVars=$(echo ${message} | grep -o "\${\w*}")

    for messageVar in ${messageVars[*]}; do
      messageVar=${messageVar#*\{}
      messageVar=${messageVar%\}*}
      messageVarVal=${!messageVar}

      echo "messageVar: ${messageVar}"
      echo "messageVarVal: ${messageVarVal}"
      message=${message//"\${${messageVar}}"/"${messageVarVal}"}
    done

    echo "Message: ${message}"
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: `for x in ${arrayName[*]}` is basically always the wrong thing; the only semantic differences between that and `for x in "${arrayName[@]}"` are strictly undesirable.